# Merge two distributed asynchronous tasks results and trigger an action

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I have the following complex scenario and looking forward for the best solution:

```
- The first async process calls a third-party service and gets an Id
- The second async process gets an attribute from a client and tries two update a record in database based on the Id from the first part and the new attribute.
```

Also I would mention that the both above async tasks are triggered inside different APIs(spring boot based restful APIS) and they are not inside the same method. In other words, it is a kinda of problem in a distributed system.

The silliest solution would be having a loop to wait for the first async task result and complete the whole process.

Any suggestion?

Comment: use `CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> getIdFromThirdService())
                .thenApply(id -> updateRecord(id));`

Comment: You may checkout using `CompletableFuture` with `@Async` .Most probably defining a `@Async` method that return `CompletableFuture` ....

Comment: _You may checkout using CompletableFuture with @Async_ what you mean?

Comment: The author originally tags the question with `spring-boot` , so i think he may be interested in how spring supports `CompletableFuture` too . `@Async` is the spring annotation for asynchronous execution.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. spring-boot tag means our solution is based on spring-boot and it happens in different controllers and not inside a specific method. I updated the question and appreciate it if you could take another look at it.

Comment: Is it the same client calling both API endpoints? i.e. client gets the Id from the API then calls the second API with the Id and an attribute to update?

Comment: @codebrane no. They are called in the same time by different api calls.